# what is a true multi dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was reading a book about Javascript and saw this line;

> JavaScript does not support true multidimensional arrays, but you can
>   approximate them with arrays of arrays.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A true multi-dimensional array must be indexed with multiple indices.  An array of arrays can be indexed with a single index, which will return another array.  A true multi-dimensional array stores all its data contiguously.  An array of arrays stores all its constituent arrays arbitrarily scattered around.  This can improve iteration performance because of cache effects for true arrays.

Comment: If an array existed that let you use a single index to retrieve a "row", but did store all its data contiguously, would it necessarily be not-truly-multi-dimensional? In other words, do both of these constraints really have to be met, or only the latter?

Comment: Well note for example that in JavaScript there's no enforcement that rows of a two-dimensional array have the same number of columns.

Comment: *"An array of arrays stores all its constituent arrays arbitrarily scattered around."* is not necessarily true: in c and closely derived languages `[][]` arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

(a visual explanation that complements an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685106/125816) of [@recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44743/recursive))

In some languages (C#) there are both. The difference is in "shape" of such arrays.

```
int[3, 4] // true two-dimensional array

// it will "look" like this, rectangular shape
[[0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But when you define an array of arrays, it can easily (especially in javascript) look like this. It's called a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

```
[[0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in JavaScript like...

```
var arr = new Array[5][3]; /* Some weird JS/C-like thing for demonstration */
```

...with enforced lengths. Like a matrix.

However, you can build an `Array` of which its members are all `Array`s of a fixed length. If one of the sub `Array`s were to have a different length, it would be a *jagged* `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

The author seems to assume that a “true” multidimensional array is one where all elements:

- Are arrays;
- Are stored by value, not by reference; and
- Have the same length.

JavaScript arrays may contain other arrays, but not by value, only by reference. That is, the elements of each row may be contiguous in memory, but the rows themselves may not. Further, there is no way to statically indicate that all of the inner arrays must have the same length, because JavaScript is dynamically typed.

But an array of arrays is precisely what you ought to use to represent a multidimensional array in JavaScript, and the details of the internal representation are probably not relevant to you when you’re just learning the language.

Answer (score 1):

> Although the JavaScript specification (3.0) does not make mention of multi-dimensional arrays, they are in fact possible. Multi-dimensional arrays can be represented by arrays of arrays. [See](http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/019.html).

For example.

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
alert(items[0][0]); // Would alert 1
```

One dimensional array in Javascript.

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
a[[2]] === a[2]; // this is true

2 == [2] //true
// Even complex
2 == [[[2]]]  //true

// And even more
var a = { "xyz" : 1 };
a[[[["xyz"]]]] === a["xyz"];  //true
```